# Alterar password de login no laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando alterar o password de login do usuário no laravel, para logar eu uso o Auth::atempt e como parâmetro o email e password, esse password não existe na minha tabela users. Onde o laravel pega esse password?
Tentei alterar dessa forma e recebi o erro abaixo:

```
    function login(Request $request){
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->senha])){
            return response()->json([
                'token' => str_random(60),
                'usuario_recruta' => Auth::User()->usuario_recruta,
                'nomeUsuario' => Auth::User()->nome,
                'idUsuario' =>Auth::User()->id,
                'mensagem' => 'Autenticado com sucesso',
            ], 202);
        }else{
        return response()->json([
        'error' => 'Nome de usuário ou senha incorretos',
        'code' => 401,], 401);
    }
}
```

O login funciona normalmente mesmo eu não tendo a coluna "password" no meu bd. Eu troquei de password para "senha", mas continua fazendo login normal.

Então eu tentei trocar dessa forma:

```
function alteraDadosPerfil($id, Request $request){
    $dadosPerfil = User::find($id);


    $dadosPerfil->password = $request->senha;

    $dadosPerfil->save();
    return response()->json($dadosPerfil, 200);
}
```

Eu recebo:

```
Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
```

Tentei também:

```
$dadosPerfil->senha = Hash::make($request->senha);

$dadosPerfil->save();
```

Porém dessa forma eu nao consigo realizar login com a senha trocada

Como eu troco a senha no laravel através de api?

Comment: Quais são os campos da tabela!?

Comment: E porque alterou a tabela!?

Comment: troquei para senha porque queria manter na lingua portuguesa

Comment: Mas já consegui, vou adicionar minha resposta quando tiver tempo